# Reading the contents of a file into a richtextbox. But recognising new lines

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io, richtextbox

This is the code I have so far. However obviously its putting everything into a list and inserting that into a text box but the problem I'm having is I'm unsure how to get it to recognise new lines and make a new list. I roughly know what I need to do but I'm having a hard time imagining it.

```
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> lines = File.ReadLines("Help.md").ToList();

        foreach (string current in lines)
        {
            HelpTextBox.Text += current;
        }
    }
```

What should I do, I think I need some sort of selection to check if a new line has started in my file?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `HelpTextBox.Text += File.ReadAllText("Help.md");`

Comment: Compiler Error CS0029

Comment: Dmitry's code seems right; check you didn't typo it eg putting ReadLines (returns enumerator) vs ReadAllText

Comment: ReadLines/ReadAllLines process the file into individual lines as they read. If you have a 2000 line file you'll get 2000 array items/2000 emits from an enumerator but they will be strings without any line delimiters (crlf etc) embedded, so if you then append them all serially to a TextBox you'll run all the lines together into one in the TextBox. ReadAllText reads the file as a single string and keeps any embedded line endings, which the TextBox will then use to render the content how you're expecting (as separate lines)

Comment: I did not mispell I got a Compiler Error CS0029, specifically *Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list<char>' to 'system.collections.generic.list<char>'* However his answer below works. Thank you for taking the time to reply!!

Comment: As another note, there's not much point in using ReadLines if you're going to ToList it immediately. ReadLines is for performing an incremental read; it returns a line at a time as they are read, so you wouldn't burn 10gb of memory to load a 10gb file. If you're going to load lines of a file straight into a collection and fully read the file before you enumerate you might as well use ReadAllLines, but strive to do incremental processing - here you run a foreach, which would really be OK as `foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(...))` (but you shouldn't use File.XxxLines at all here)

Comment: I understand this now. The application is in early development and I was just going through some of our issues. I didn't need to put it in a list as I established earlier with Dmitry. Thank you again. Merry Christmas to you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not load *entire* `Help.md` file and set `Text` in *one go*?

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelpTextBox.Text += File.ReadAllText("Help.md");
}
```

Comment: Yes! Of course! I don't know why I was putting it into a list

Comment: Completely on board with you there, again I'm not sure why I put that in there. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would recommend removing the second code block; code like that would ideally be filed under the "just because you can, doesn't mean you should" heading  (I understand why you put it, but for a 160k rep user to even mention might come across as a recommendation)